# Delete certain property records in a form array using forEach

Tags: angular

I wish to loop through a form array and remove a certain property (in this case I want to remove the `newLanguage` property).

Would the approach be:

```
this.myForm['controls'].languages['controls'].forEach((element) => {
 delete element['controls'].newLanguage;
});
```

Comment: do you want to remove particular formcontrol from formArray?

Comment: @Chellappanவ yes the newLanguage is a formcontrol. I'm unsure how to remove a formcontrol whilst in forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude **newLanguage** value form formGroup, Then you can disable formControl by calling [disable](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable) method.

```
this.myForm['controls'].languages['controls'].forEach((element) => {
    element['controls'].get('newLanguage').disable();
});
```

**OR**

If you want to remove formControl from FormGroup then you need to call [removeControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#removeControl) method and pass the control name to it

```
this.myForm['controls'].languages['controls'].forEach((element) => {
    element['controls'].removeControl('newLanguage');
});
```